# NSDate timeIntervalSince1970 not working in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am doing this in swift:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1432233446145.0)
println("date is \(date)")
```

The log gives me this:

```
 date is 47355-09-02 23:55:45 +0000
```

Then I try to get an interval back out just for testing:

```
let tI = expirationDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(date)
println("tI = \(tI)")
```

I get:

tI = 0.0

What am I doing wrong?
I can seem to make the timeIntervalSince1970 call work properly. Is there any known issued with that in Swift, or am I missing something here?

Comment: What output were you expecting exactly?

Comment: What's in expirationDate?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`1432233446145` most probably is a time interval given in *milliseconds*:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1432233446145.0/1000.0)
print("date is \(date)")
// date is 2015-05-21 18:37:26 +0000
```

**Swift 3 and later:**

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1432233446145.0/1000.0)
```

Comment: Time interval was wrong. It was in milliseconds so dividing by 1000.0 did the trick. Simple fix, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

I think your timestamp is incorrect. This results in your date being september 2nd, 47355.

If I use the following I get the date for (right about) now:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1431024488)
println("date is \(date)")
// "date is 2015-05-07 18:48:08 +0000"
```

The printed date is not a localized timestamp, so you'll have to do some localization of your own I suppose. An example:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
println("formatted date is \(formatter.stringFromDate(date))")
// "formatted date is 07-05-2015 20:48:08"
```

And for completeness I also checked with an expiration date that's 1100 seconds larger than the initial `date`:

```
let expirationDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1431025588)
let diff = expirationDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(date)
println("expires in: \(diff)")
// "expires in: 1100.0"
```

So, the timeIntervalSince1970 seems to work fine, I think your interval was just not what you wanted it to be.

Answer (score -4):

From your code and the log content follows:

```
date.isEqual(expirationDate)
```

--> Your stuff has just expired :-).

Comment: The time interval is zero.

Comment: How do you know, you don't know what's in expirationDate

Comment: The check with the result 0.0 reveals it. Never mind, you are not getting my irony.