# Big int to date time format in swift

Tags: swift, datetime-format, bigint

I am new to programming in Swift. I want to know how to convert bigint data stored at the server to datetime format in a tableview.

This is what I have done so far:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let sdates: Double = Double(data.dates!)!     
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: sdates)

// Returns date formatted as 12 hour time.
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd hh:mm a"
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
cell.datetime.text = data.dates

return cell
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "bigint data"? What is your input value? What is the expected and actual result?

Comment: "1463653800000" this is the data that i have at server i want to convert to convert it to date time format

Comment: That is a timespan in *milliseconds*, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109219/nsdate-timeintervalsince1970-not-working-in-swift.

Comment: Thank mate that was helpful...thanks a lot