# Unix dateTime format not properly converted in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, unix, swift5

Using alamofire İ am fetching JSON data in swift. 
Time value is integer and have iso8601 format. When İ am converting Unix datetime which in integer format from back end gives me weird value.

`1570088096210` must have to convert to `GMT: Thursday, October 3, 2019 7:34:56.210 AM` but giving me `51724-02-10T10:16:00+00:00`

> Code:

```
 let dateValue = Double(AppData.time ?? 0)
 let dateFinal = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dateValue).formattedISO8601
```

Comment: What is `formattedISO8601`?

Comment: Compare [NSDate timeIntervalSince1970 not working in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109219/nsdate-timeintervalsince1970-not-working-in-swift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are getting `milliseconds` that you need to convert to `seconds` before creating `date` as,

```
let time: TimeInterval = 1570088096210/1000
let dateFinal = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: time)
print(dateFinal.description)
```

> 2019-10-03 07:34:56 +0000

Answer (score 1):

You are encouraged to use `Decodable` to parse the JSON. It can handle *millisecondsSince1970* very smoothly including the conversion to `Date`

```
let json = """
{"date":1570088096210}
"""

struct PointInTime : Decodable {
    let date : Date
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
    let result = try decoder.decode(PointInTime.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(result.date) // 2019-10-03 07:34:56 +0000
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: cannot convert model structure data type. at back end it has integer data type.

Comment: Look at the literal JSON. The date type **is** integer. And you can encode it back to integer with the same strategy. `Codable` is extremely flexible.

Answer (score 0):

`1570088096210` is actually `02/10/51724 @ 10:16pm (UTC)`

Please, check your income data